# Why is the Latent heat of solid to gas equal to the sum of latent heat of solid to liquid and the latent heat of liquid to gas?

Tags: thermodynamics

What is the mathematical reason as to why the following is through at the triple point temperature $T_3$?

$$ L_{solid -> gas} = L_{solid -> liquid} + L_{liquid -> gas}$$

Where $L$ is latent heat.

I tried convincing myself through the idea of state functions of the system, where only the final and initial states matters. However, I ran into a problem because latent heat $L$ is effectively the heat abosrbed during a change of state, however, heat $Q$ is not a state function itself.

Answer (score 0):

A good explanation , why enthalpy $\Delta H$ is a state function, is because $\Delta H = \Delta U - \Delta (pV)$. Notice that the functions on the right are state functions. Hence, enthalpy is a state function.

So this means if the system changes state from a given set of pressure, volume and temperature variables ,to another, enthalpy is always same for the same state change.

Comment: Hi, can I ask then how is enthalpy related to latent heat?